# Processing dbscan by group

Tags: postgis, point, clustering

I am new to PostGIS and I need to do DBSCAN by commune.
I have the base dir_v2:

1. id_dir
2. geom
3. commune

I need to process clustering at least 1000 points in a radius of 1000 meters per commune but it doesn't work

```
CREATE TABLE cob_fibra_cluster_2 AS (
  SELECT id_dir,geom,
    ST_ClusterDBscan (ST_Transform (geom,32719),1000,1000) OVER () AS id_cluster
  FROM dir_v2 
  GROUP BY commune);
```

Comment: what doesnt work? do you get an error?

Comment: ERROR:  la columna «dir_v2.id_dir» debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación
LINE 2: (SELECT id_dir,geom,
                ^
SQL state: 42803
Character: 45

Comment: in english please

Comment: ERROR: The column "dir_v2.id_dir" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in a LINE 2 aggregation function: (SELECT id_dir, geom, ^ SQL state: 42803 Character: 45 -

Answer (score 3):

DBScan should run by commune directly, and not on the entire table + grouped by commune.

The `window` function must be configured. Note that the cluster ID will start at 0 again for each different commune. You may also want to filter for NULL cluster ID (i.e. points that are not part of a cluster)

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id_dir, commune, geom,
         ST_ClusterDBscan (ST_Transform (geom,32719),1000,1000) OVER (PARTITION BY commune) AS id_cluster
  FROM dir_v2) dc
WHERE dc.id_cluster IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I need the dbscan to be processed by commune. that in each commune perform the clustering

Comment: @MarceloEstebanLagosBustaman that is exactly what my answer is doing. Have you tried it?